# Predicting children growth

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, multivariate-distribution

I am doing a project where I am supposed to forecast future athletes' performance one, two, three, etc. years in the future. The dataset consists of athletes' scores on tests done from they were kids until their current age and some historical athletes' entire career. There are several different tests, some of the tests are dependent on each other, and I want to forecast each test. I assume this is a multivariate time series forecasting problem, but I am not sure this is the best way to go. I have read that time series forecasting requires constant mean and standard deviation, which of course is not the case.

What kind of ML models are most fitting to such a problem?

Hope to hear from anyone.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Actually my intuition would be not to treat this as a time series forecasting problem, but rather a regular supervised regression problem. In other words, the model would only try to measure if the input child profile fits the 'future athlete' profile. It might even make sense to design this as one-class classification problem, depending on the diversity of non-athlete profiles.

Comment: Thank you and thank you for your reply. There is some diversity in the dataset, not all the kids in the dataset develop into professional athletes. If I understand you correctly, the classifier would classify the kids into 'athletes' and non-athletes, is that correct? Preferably I want to assess how well they will perform and to see if any needs extra training.

Comment: Additionally, can a forecasting model be used on different age groups? Or would it be more effective to divide the kids into different age groups and build a predictive model for each group?

Comment: Yes. something like this, but instead of a binary class you could predict a numerical value which represents their future performance (regression). I'm not really expert in forecasting so I'm not sure about your last question.